# symfony2 utf8 issue with translation in the controller

Tags: php, json, ajax, symfony, utf-8

In my symfony 2 application, I am translating a string in a controller, from a yaml file, and sending it via ajax.

Then in my ajax function, I am parsing the response with JSON

The issue I have is the string that is being output by the translator is not in UTF8. Why? It is in the right format when I call the filter | trans in my templates.

Also, accentuated letters written in my controller are correctly sent in UTF8, it really seems to come from the translating component.

The workaround I found is to encode in UTF8 after it is translated in my controller, send it via ajax, then decode UTF8 in javascript. But it's not super clean plus I can get "this is not a URI" errors.

**How can I have the translator output a UTF8 string in my controller ?**

My yaml:

```
rights:
    is_boss: Tout éditer, voir, supprimer
```

My controller:

```
    $message= strtolower($translator->trans('rights.is_boss', array(), 'backend_pages'));

    $response = array(
        'message' => utf8_encode($message)
    );

    return new JsonResponse($this->get('serializer')->serialize($response, 'json'));
```

My view:

```
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST',
            url         : '{{ path('manage_rights', {'associate' : associate.id }) }}',
            data: {right: right, parameter: parameter, value: value},
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function(response){
            response = JSON.parse(response);
            var message = decodeURIComponent(escape(response.message));
            //do stuff
        })
```

The error I get if I don't encode in UTF 8 is the following:

> Your data could not be encoded because it contains invalid UTF8
>   characters. 500 Internal Server Error - RuntimeException
>   in
>   vendor\jms\serializer\src\JMS\Serializer\JsonSerializationVisitor.php
>   at line 36   -

Precision:

```
//This does not output a proper UTF8 string. I get an error if I try to serialize it in JSON
$message= strtolower($translator->trans('rights.is_boss', array(), 'backend_pages'));

//In my twig, this does output a correct string with accentuated chars without weird symbols
<label>{{ ('rights.is_boss') | trans }}</label>
```

Comment: What exactly is happening when it *doesn't* work?!

Comment: Try putting your translation text into "" ..  "Tout éditer, voir, supprimer"

Comment: @deceze I added the error details, it's a utf8 error in the serializer. And putting quotes did not solve the issue

Comment: You must configure your editor to save files in UTF-8. Additionally, get rid of `utf8_encode()`—you don't need it and you probably don't even know what it does.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: I am using PhpStorm and everything is set to UTF8 encoding in the Editor->File Encodings (IDE encoding, Project encoding, Default encoding all set to UTF8)

Comment: Does it work if you replace `strtolower()` and similar functions with their multi-byte alternatives? (`mb_strtolower()` etc)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: no, I unfortunately get the same error. Any idea as to how diagnose this better ?

Comment: You apparently don't know for sure where in your app stack your data gets corrupted. I think that determining that should be the first step. Even poor man's debugging (var_dump + bin2hex) should allow that.

Comment: well, so it comes from the strtolower. the same with mb_strtolower. If I remove it, it works fine. I'll look into this